# I am unable to see the server deployed by Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin

I'm using Windows 7, running rails through cygwin.

I ran `$ rails server -b localhost`

And this was the output:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

However Google Chrome reported: `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3000`

How do I go about rectifying this issue?

More information: Using the default sqlite3 server, and I have tried `127.0.0.1:3000` and `0.0.0.0:3000` and received the same response

Comment: Can you try without the -b option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried rails server on localhost, you can run rails server without -b option, The -b option binds rails use when you try with specified ip.

Try this for see rails run on production :

> rails server -e production -p 4000

[Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)